# What can cause a PHP script to simply stop while creating a text variable?

Tags: php, mysql

I am having the weirdest issue that I've been trying to track for months now. I've added lines and lines of debugging code that create log entries in a MySQL based log, and the result makes no sense.

Basically, the script simply stops sometimes. Sometimes it does so randomly, then it does it a dozen times in the same location, then it might continue all the way through, then it does it again the next time.

More details:

Every 15 minutes, I am looping through a list of clients, and every client has a list of data that needs to be parsed and collected for emails. If a previous version of this script is already running (i.e. a log entry exists that is less than 5 minutes old), the script is not executed again. So if I see a break in log entries longer than a few minutes and then another start 15 minutes after the first start, I know something is wrong. The most bizarre situation from the log is as follows:

I put into the log that I am about to create the database query for client X. Then I create a variable with SQL code that contains the client id and the day of the week ( `date("l", strtotime("now"))` ). Then I log that the query was created successfully. Note that the query ONLY exists in a PHP variable and was NOT submitted to MySQL yet!

So let me give you an example of what I see in the log:

- 3:00:00pm - (script starts)
- 3:00:00pm - (it loops through clients)
- 3:00:04pm - (it has gone through some clients and is now working on client 20)
- 3:00:04pm - creating query for client 20
- (log ends here until the script is automatically restarted 15 minutes later if there has not been any log entry for at least 5 minutes)
- 3:15:00pm - (script starts)
- 3:15:00pm - (it loops through clients)
- 3:15:04pm - (it has gone through some clients, is skipping client 20 because that obviously had a problem, and is now working on client 21)
- 3:15:04pm - creating query for client 21
- 3:15:04pm - successfully created query for client 21
- (log ends here until the script is automatically restarted 15 minutes later if there has not been any log entry for at least 5 minutes)
- 3:30:00pm - (script starts)
- 3:30:00pm - (it loops through clients)
- 3:30:04pm - (it has gone through some clients and is now working on client 20)
- 3:30:04pm - creating query for client 20

And rinse and repeat. Now for a few hours, it will alternate between failing just before it creates the query for client 20 and failing just after it created the query for client 21. Then, suddenly, it might make it all the way through the rest of the clients. Then the script starts again and will continue the same weird loop. And every day or so, this will happen with one or two other clients.

The query is simple enough, something like this:

```
$sql = "
select fldClientName
from client
where fldClientId = $clientId
and fldEmail".date("l", strtotime("now"))." = 1
";
```

Basically, if today is Monday, it should check if fldEmailMonday is set to 1 to let us know that this client needs to be emailed today.

This works for tons of our clients, but it just randomly gets stuck at one or two clients that change from day to day. And again, this happens BEFORE `$sql` is submitted to MySQL! We get stuck in the creation of the variable `$sql`.

Granted, the actual query is much more complex than what I've written here, but `$clientId` and `date("l", strtotime("now"))` are the only variable parts in an otherwise static piece of text.

Furthermore, we've had the same issue over years (I've only now started tracking it down more), and by now, we have gone through three PHP servers and two MySQL servers - and we're still having the same issue, so we're moderately sure it's not a hardware issue (like memory or hard drive).

I don't know if this might be the problem, but this script is run by a cron job that starts it in lynx. This was established before I took on the code, and I don't know the reason for it. Whenever we run it manually (I usually use `php index.php` instead of `lynx hostname://index.php`), it doesn't seem to fail, ever.

So could this be an issue with Lynx? If so, why does it work 70% of the time and fail otherwise? Why the randomness?

Or is there a PHP issue that I should figure out? We're running version 5.3.2 (yes, a bit old, but our server admin doesn't want to mess with it unless absolutely necessary).

I am guessing that Lynx is used so we get the Apache log (which by the way is empty except for some deprecated code warnings that I'm trying to get rid of now, too), and I am guessing that if I run `php index.php`, I don't get an apache log. Maybe there's another log file I'm missing that might help here?

Also, it can't be the logging code itself that's causing it because it only submits plain static text and the client id that is established before the SQL code is created.

The script fails in plenty more locations, but this is the one that really makes no sense to me.

Any thoughts at all on what could cause something like this?

Any thoughts on what else I can do to track it down? I mean, I'm logging right before and after I create a variable, and it dies in between - now sure how much more I could be logging here...

Comment: I'd advise you to cut this question down by at least half if you can - there's a lot of extreme detail there, but not much code to cross-reference. There must be more to it than the one line you have shown?

Comment: Yes, there is more SQL code in there, but it's not relevant because it is all static - nothing changes except for the section I have outlined. I'll gladly post the whole thing, but I don't think it's useful. I literally have the log line, the variable declaration, and another log line in my code - nothing else - and it fails right between them in a pattern that I haven't figured out yet...

Comment: @halfer That is what I told my server admin, and today we'll just see what happens if he uses `php index.php` instead of lynx. I know Lynx is old and abandoned, but even a program that old shouldn't randomly die at a time when there's not even anything being thrown back at it while it can later go on for 45 minutes without a hitch... But we'll definitely try taking lynx out of the equation.

Comment: The Apache log is entire empty except for the aforementioned deprecation messages (it still used `split` for example). I haven't checked the PHP error logs - frankly wasn't sure they existed since I've never needed them - I'll look into those, thanks!

Comment: Usually PHP issues are logged with Apache errors. But it is possible for them to be configured separately - see your php.ini just in case.

Comment: Just checked - no error log defined in php.ini - so even if I run the script directly using `php index.php`, will it still create a log entry in the apache log? But in any case, right now, the apache log has no useful information about this :-(

Comment: I'm not an expert on that, but I would assume that it would not. However, if you are able to run this with the `php` binary, you may find the problem goes away of its own accord (and if it does not go away, at least you have narrowed down the problem).

Comment: What you could do is turn on all error types (using `error_reporting`) and then pipe all script output to `mail` - so you can keep an eye on it. All good cron scripts should output no errors, since everything should be handled gracefully.

Comment: Yea, once our admin comes back in, I'll make sure we get this cron job switched right away, and I figured we'd go the route of `php index.php -ddisplay_errors=E_ALL >>sslog.txt` so we log absolutely everything until we figure this out (I prefer this to email because the script outputs a lot of debugging code to screen as well from way before my time here). Thanks for your time and insight so far, by the way!

Comment: You aren't hitting max_execution_time ceiling by chance, are you?  How long does this script need to run when being run from the PHP binary manually?  Another issue is that lynx might be timing out the request while it's being made due to not receiving any data back from the request over a certain amount of time.

Comment: The weird thing is that sometimes it stops within 4 seconds of starting, and another time it will run for 45 minutes until the script naturally stops...

Comment: Today will be the first day that the updated cron job will run through its data by itself, so tomorrow I can check the logs, and hopefully it'll just be a Lynx problem. We'll know for sure on Monday because it's the Saturday and Sunday script executions that have caused the biggest issues. I ran it manually yesterday and then let it run on its own for the rest of the night, and it ran without glitches as far as I can tell, so fingers crossed :-)

Comment: @halfer We just had our first (ever?) successful fun of the cron job over the weekend - only because I dropped lynx in favor of a plain PHP command line command. Please create a quick answer about your suspicions of lynx so I can pick it as an answer. Thanks for everyone chiming in!

Comment: Done - pleased it worked for you!

Comment: Oops, "run", not "fun" ... Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To summarise the conversation, my main strategy was to simplify the number of software components involved in the cron call. So, this means changing from:

```
Cron -> Lynx -> Apache -> Script
```

to

```
Cron -> Script
```

If problems are still exhibited in the new approach, then at least two components have been ruled out (and it may be faster too). It sounds like, from your comments, that this fixed it; if so, great.

A wider point I'd reiterate here is that, whilst a challenging problem can be interesting to look into, there is a point where for cost reasons it is best to solve the problem another way. This may be such an occasion, and the mystery of Lynx failing might just have to persist!

Comment: I honestly don't know why we originally used Lynx (other than Apache logging - which now is no longer needed thanks for sending all output into a log file). But taking Lynx out of the equation fixed it. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

It might be your issue is not related to PHP, MySQL or Apache, might be more of server environment case, some OS freezing and dropping zombies case.
Did you try that cronjobs in any other environment than Lynx? i mean maybe locally or at some other server.

Have you checked up server logs for any alert/error messages?

Comment: We've done this on 3 PHP servers and 2 MySQL servers with these results. The one common denominator MAY be that we're using Lynx.

Comment: The thing is that usually db & code issues are usually more easily traced back than that from a server, and you spent some really long hours hunting this bug down. This is why i assumed it was from a server. 

And more of that - you can easily try to catch this issue at your localhost. If this issue won't popup at your localhost using the current code, then i'm 100% sure the case is a server related. And at least it'll give you a new direction to dig in.

Comment: Yes, it is possible that it is indeed a server issue - as far as I know, all 3 PHP servers were running the same Linux and PHP version, so there may be a bug there. However, tracking that down would be a nightmare - we'd have to experiment with new server software, copy all our database and code over, setup a test account with the API to which I'm the resulting data - and even then we'd basically have to wait until the code fails again. The failures are so random, that's the problem... If switching away from Lynx doesn't fix it, we'll definitely have to try your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

My first step in debugging this would be to extract the day variable from the $sql generation. I can't see anything wrong with it so I doubt it'll accomplish much, but at least it'll confirm one way or the other if that is contributing to the problem.

```
$day = date("l", strtotime("now"));
$sql = "
select fldClientName
from client
where fldClientId = $clientId
and fldEmail{$day} = 1
";
```

You could even check the value of `$day` and throw a RuntimeException if it isn't valid. But as I mentioned, I suspect the answer lies elsewhere.

Comment: Hm, yea, as you said: Unlikely - but given the weirdness of the situation, I wouldn't rule it out as impossible...